# Name is returning null in Collections?

Tags: java, collections

This is my first class

```
    public class User {

   String name;
   int age;

   public User(String name,int age)
   {
    name=this.name;
    age=this.age;
   }

  @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj)
   {
    User u=(User)obj;
    if(this.age==u.age)
    {
        return this.name.equals(u.name);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
     }
     }

    public int hashcode()
   {
     return this.name.hashCode()+this.age;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString()
    {
    return String.format("Name %s", this.name);
   }
   }
```

This is my second class

```
   public class MainClass {

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
    java.util.Set s=new java.util.HashSet();
    s.add(new Integer(10));
    s.add(new Integer(1));
    s.add(new Integer(5));
    s.add(new Integer(3));
    s.add(new Integer(6));
    s.add(new Integer(9));
    s.add(new User("Amit",25));
    s.add(new User("Amit",25));
    java.util.Iterator it=s.iterator();
     while(it.hasNext())
     {
         System.out.println(it.next());
    }
   }

   }
```

**When I run my second program name is returned as null.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Martijn Courteaux and Subhrajyoti Majumder alredy said, you have to change the assignment in the constructor.

Another mistake is your hashCode Method. It needs an capitalized C, so like that:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int i = this.name.hashCode() + this.age;
    return i;
}
```

The @Override annotation is a nice check for such errors.

**Explanation:** Your class `User` has a method `hashcode` that doesn't override the `hashCode` Method in `Object`. But exactly that method is used by the `HashSet` to check for Equality of Objects (hence the name `HashSet`).

Answer (score 2):

`this.name` refers the instance name object and `name` refers the local name object. It should be -

```
public User(String name,int age){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
}
```

`name=this.name;` here local reference is assigned instance reference which assigned `null` as default so it is getting null.

Comment: but now it is permitting duplicate values `Amit` is printing two times.

Comment: Can you please make the `Set` type safe like - `Set<User>`

Comment: No due to some reasons I cn't.

Answer (score 1):

You're assignment is wrong. The syntax of the assignment is: `variable = value;`.

```
public User(String name,int age)
{
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
```

So, what your code did, was changing the value of the constructor parameters, instead of using these parameters to instantiate the object members.

Comment: but now it is permitting duplicate values `Amit` is printing two times.

Answer (score 1):

This is because public int hashcode() is wrong implementation of hashcode.
This would be :

public int hashCode()